# Laravel 5.2 how to update migration without losing data

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm using laravel 5.2 and I usually update my database according to project requirements, so I'd like to do it without losing database records.
I don't mean how to seed my database.. I mean when my database is live and I want to update it throw laravel migration.
I was going throw [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations) but I found nothing, so I hope to find somebody help me

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Since you already have data in your tables then instead of rolling back your migrations (which will cause existing data losses) you can create new migration files to update your tables. Suppose you have a table `users` with columns `name, email, password`. You stored data in that table. Then you realized that you also do need to add a new column named `mobile_no` to your users table. To do this you need to create a new migration file. Command will be:

```
php artisan make:migration add_mobile_no_columns_to_users_table --table=users
```

This way a new migration file will be created. Set your column details there, run the migrations using `php artisan migrate` and that's all. You'll have this new column in your `users` table without losing previously stored data.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works smoothly.
can I use the same way when update table relationships?

Comment: Yes you can. Difference is updating relationships is bit different. For already declared foreign key with index you need to drop index, drop foreign key name then drop column. Unless it may generates error. You can find more details on https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#indexes

Comment: Thanks @Mahfuzul Alam

Comment: Mahfuzul Alam ...Very nice solution...exactly surfing for this one...thank you!

Comment: Many time i tried various methods to do this ,but this time with your answer i got final solution.

Answer (score 13):

Please note that when you add a new column for a table while already there are data, you have to set a default value for new column or make it nullable type..  otherwise you will endup with error

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that when you are adding new column in your table, that column should be nullable, and should not be unique. Otherwise you will face error. Because when a new column is created it will be empty(not unique). In that condition you have to rollback the migration.

Answer (score 3):

Make a new migration with

```
php artisan make:migration change_body_to_nullable_in_reviews_table --table=reviews
```

where you put this

```php
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('body')->nullable()->change();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->text('body')->nullable(false)->change();
        });
    }
```

And then run PHP artisan migrate